# obtain mass on chest,biceps,triceps program

Tags: exercise, workout, biceps, chest

i make workout only friday,Saturday,Sunday.Rarely and other days.I am 24 years old and  my weight is 66.My height is 1.78.Can someone build chest,biceps and triceps making workout only the days i reffered?i am doing twice a day ,morning and afternoon from 1 hour and after each my workout i eat protein and fruits and food.I only can workout these days.Will i succeed ?which is the pefect weight  you think for my pounds and for my height to be presentable?

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone build chest,biceps and triceps making workout only the days i reffered?i am doing twice a day

Yes, 3 days per week is adequate.

> Will i succeed ?

We don't know. It depends entirely on your discipline, your diet, your sleep, and your motivation.

> which is the pefect weight you think for my pounds and for my height to be presentable?

That depends on our individual notions of what is presentable, and such opinion-based questions/answers are off-topic here.

**The question you *should* be asking**, or rather the question I should ask you is; are you really going to just train chest and arms? Because if so:

> Will i succeed ?

No. You will end up with ridiculous proportions, and more importantly, back pain, neck pain, and the resulting loss of quality of life.

**Any workout program should work your entire body!**